# How send input type file to image upload file using post method in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

How send input type file to image upload file using post method in JavaScript?
Blew is the form.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image_upload" name="image_upload">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" onchange="readURL(this);" required>
    <br>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here blow is JavaScript that I have used for post the Form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#image_upload').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('getfile_provider.php',$('#image_upload').serialize(),function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

    });
});
```

When i send in this method i get in getfile_provider.php file only the user_id value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload file through Jquery/AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920322/how-to-upload-file-through-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to  sending image file using post method

```
 var formData = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "getfile_provider.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert('done');
            });
```

Comment: This img tag is show Image after file load. But i have tried after you comments. Still is not parsing the value from File load.

Comment: @sanji its my mistake please check my updated answer!!